# remove autoexec macro from MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have created an autoexec macro in MS Access 2007 and cannot find it!

I know its there because it runs, but I cannot find it to delete or modify.  I can see other macros that I have created just not the autoexec one.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to find where it is located .... cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you know if the AutoExec macro is hidden?

If so, right click your left hand pane, and select *Navigation Options*.

Make sure that under *Display Options* that the *Show Hidden Objects* is check.

THis should then show you all hidden objects, and you should be able to access the *AutoExec* macro

-

Alternaticely, you can click the *Office Button* in the top left hand corner.

Select *Access Options*, and *Current Database*.

Under *Navigation*, click the *Navigation Options* and follow the rest above.

Comment: Just tried that .... no go I also selected show system objects and still nothing.  thanks.

Comment: It should be under the **Unrelated Objects Tab**

Comment: thanks again.  I never found it but did manage a workaround.  Create a new macro and rename it autoexec, dialogue box asks if I want to override, yes, then delete the new autoexec macro while it is still visible within the navigation pane.